# Is it valid to bind non-const lvalue-references to rvalues in C++ 11?(modified)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

I know in c++03, an an non-const reference cannot be bound to rvalues.

`T& t = getT();` is invalid, and in c++11, we can do this: `T&& t = getT();`  but what about the above code, should that work in c++11?

I tested the codes below with vs11:

```
 Foo getFoo() {
  return Foo();
}

void fz(Foo& f) {
}

int getInt() {
  return int();
}

void iz(int& i) {
}

int main() {
  {
    Foo& z = getFoo(); //ok
    fz(getFoo()); //ok

    int& z2 = getInt(); //error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
    iz(getInt()); //same as above
  }
}
```

`Foo` is a custom class, I don't understand why the first two line compiles.The temporary referenced by `z` is destructed at the end of the inner scope of main. Does the standard say anything about this?

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {
    std::cout << "constructed\n";
  }
  ~Foo() {
    std::cout << "destructed\n";
  }
};
```

I just saw a similar question: [One VS2010 bug ? Allowing binding non-const reference to rvalue WITHOUT EVEN a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189420/one-vs2010-bug-allowing-binding-non-const-reference-to-rvalue-without-even-a-w?rq=1)

Comment: It's interesting how *few* Objective-C or Java programmers ask questions about language-oriented esoterica like "Is it valid to bind rvalues to non-const lvalue-references...?" Or have to concern themselves with stuff like "temporary references...destructed at the end of the inner scope".  Just sayin' ;)

Comment: Could you post how you defined Foo.

Comment: binding rules have not changed wrt Lvalue references AFAIK

Comment: @paulsm4: Sorry I didn't have time to read your comment, I was too busy waiting for your garbage collector to finish.

Comment: @paulsm4 Objective-C didn't always have automatic reference counting, you know. There was plenty of messiness before that was introduced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> should that work in c++11?

No, it should not.

> `Foo` is a custom class, I don't understand why the first two line compiles

It compiles only with MSVC. MSVC has an (arguably useful) *compiler extension* that allows binding lvalues of user-defined types to rvalues, but the Standard itself forbids this. See, for instance, [this live example](http://ideone.com/TzGfy7) where GCC 4.7.2 refuses to compile your code.

> Does the standard say anything about this?

Indeed it does. Per paragraph 8.5.3/5 of the C++11 Standard:

> A reference to type “`cv1 T1`” is initialized by an expression of type “`cv2 T2`” as follows:
>
> — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
> > — is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “`cv1 T1`” is reference-compatible with “`cv2 T2`,” or
> >
> > — has a class type (i.e., `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, and can be
> >     implicitly converted to an lvalue of type “`cv3 T3`,” where “`cv1 T1`” is reference-compatible with “`cv3
> >     T3`” [...],
>
> then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case and to the lvalue result
>   of the conversion in the second case (or, in either case, to the appropriate base class subobject of
>   the object). [...]
>
> [ ...]
>
> — **Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be
>   const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference**. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> double& rd2 = 2.0; // error: not an lvalue and reference not const
> int i = 2;
> double& rd3 = i; // error: type mismatch and reference not const
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Answer (score 1):

No you can't bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference.

```
T f();

T& t1 = f(); // won't compile
const T& t2 = f(); // OK
T&& t3 = f(); // OK
```

This is a safety feature.  Mutating a temporary by an lvalue that is about to die anyway is most likely a logic error, so it isn't allowed by the language.

Note that due to the RVO than in practice:

```
T&& t3 = f();
```

and

```
T t3 = f();
```

are equivilent.