# Does C++11 permit taking a reference to an anonymous temporary

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function `void foo(const std::string& s)` which I'd like to call using `foo(s.substr(pos))`.

In MSVC (implementing C++98), this compiled fine, but an old compiler for posix would error with "cannot take a reference of an anonymous temporary". That makes me think that taking a reference to an anonymous temporary is not permitted in standard C++98.

But, is it permitted in C++11?

Comment: What is a "posix compiler"? The code above will certainly be accepted by GCC and Clang. It will only fail if you remove the `const` - which will also make VC++ fail, independent of C++98 or C++11.

Comment: I think I read on SO that you can take a reference to an anonymous temporary as long as it is a **reference to a const object**. Which is your case.

Comment: This is [perfectly legal C++](http://ideone.com/G4la9d), and has been since C++98 (and likely before). Your "posix compiler" is incorrect.

Comment: @Bathsheba You seem to misremember that, even GCC 2.95 got that right. I would bet you just remembered the non-const case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++98 as well as C++11 accept a temporary when binding a `const` reference as a parameter. The following works:

```
void foo( const std::string& s );

foo( s.substr( pos ) ); // OK
```

If you want to take a non-const reference, the standard/compiler sees this as a hint that you need the modified result, which is impossible to access as it is a temporary. Hence the following does not work:

```
void foo( std::string& s );

foo( s.substr( pos ) ); // not OK
```

Note that with C++11, you can overload `foo` to detect rvalues, which temporaries are. (There are others):

```
void foo( std::string& s ); // 1
void foo( std::string&& s ); // 2

foo( s.substr( pos ) ); // calls 2
```

Comment: MSVC *will* bind a temporary object to a non-`const` reference, this is likely what the OP is mis-remembering.

Comment: @Casey VC will fail with `/Za` (disable language extensions) or warn you with a high enough warning level (`/W4`? I'm not using VC...)

Answer (score 1):

> Does C++11 permit taking a reference to an anonymous temporary?

**Yes, absolutely**. So does C++03. With conditions...

> In MSVC (implementing C++98), this compiled fine, but an old compiler for posix would error with "cannot take a reference of an anonymous temporary". That makes me think that taking a reference to an anonymous temporary is not permitted in standard C++98.

I think you're remembering something slightly different. Firstly, all temporaries are "anonymous", and they can all be bound to a reference-to-`const` (the binding extends the lifetime of the temporary, though in the following example even that is not necessary):

```
int foo(const T&);
int x = foo(T());
```

This was always the case in standard C++ and before. If your old POSIX compiler did not accept it then it was horribly broken; however, I believe you're instead thinking of the following case:

```
int foo(T&);  // no `const`
int x = foo(T());
```

This is *not* legal, but Visual Studio (*only*) accepts it as a misguided non-standard exception, because Microsoft.

---

- [Is it valid to bind non-const lvalue-references to rvalues in C++ 11?(modified)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16493524/560648)
- [One VS2010 bug ? Allowing binding non-const reference to rvalue WITHOUT EVEN a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7189420/560648)