# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type in gcc but not Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I have some code where IInterface is an abstract class.

I was writing this

```
IInterface &q  = InterfaceImpl();
```

and compiled it in Visual Studio 2008 and it worked fine. Then I ported it to a gcc project and suddenly I got this error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'IInterface&' from a temporary of type 'InterfaceImpl'
```

When trying to find out what is wrong I found this thread [error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293426/error-invalid-initialization-of-non-const-reference-of-type-int-from-an-rval) and at least understand now what is wrong. So changing it to this:

```
InterfaceImpl i = InterfaceImpl();
IInterface &q = i;
```

made it compile:

However, The lifetime of these two objects are the same, so I don't really understand why gcc can not create a temporary object as apparently MS did. I assume that this is defined by the standard? When I look at the link above, I can understand why it makes no sense with something like a base type, but why does it need to get an error in case of an object?

I also tried it like this, but then I get the error that IInterface is an abstract class and can not be instantiated.

```
IInterface i = InterfaceImpl();
```

`i` should be initialized, not instantiated. Does this mean I would need a copy constructor or assignment operator in InterfaceImpl to make this work or why do I get this error?

Comment: The standard states that you can only bind a temporary object to a const reference. MSVC's behaviour is non-standard.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but how about just using `InterfaceImpl q;`?

Comment: I don't want to use it directly, because this is a simplified version of my project, to develop this part of it, without the overhead of recompiling everything until I know how this should work.The code above would't exist in the real project like this, I just happened to find this issue because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InterfaceImpl()` returns a temporary object (rvalue) that you cannot keep in a non-const reference.

However when you instantiate `IInterface i` i becomes an lvalue, So you can keep it in non-const reference.

However binding non-const reference to rvalue is allowed in VS . It has been discussed in this  [`thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189420/one-vs2010-bug-allowing-binding-non-const-reference-to-rvalue-without-even-a-w)

Comment: Doesn't really make me happy to create a second (useless) variable just to fullfill this requirement.

Comment: @Devolus: In your fake example, you don't need to create a second variable, you can just use the `InterfaceImpl` object directly.  If you present a real example, perhaps we can give you an option for that which you don't find so distasteful.

Comment: Thanks, but in the real project this variable get assigned by a function anyway, and then I don't have this issue, so It's only an artifact of the example.