# How to call a non-const overload?

Tags: c++

What's the difference betweeen `void func(const int& i)` and `void func(int& i)`. If const is cut off at the top level, is it even possible to call the second overload? Why are const overloads preferred? The following will always select the first overload:

```
func(42);
func(int{42});
int i = 42;
func(i);
int &j = i;
func(j);
func(i + 1);
```

---

Whoops, I see what my problem is now. I had typed `cout << "const\n"` in both functions, so it looked like it always calling the first overload. Sorry guys.

Comment: What is it with the `Pokemon` in the title?!

Comment: @stefan, It's a subtle hint that the OP has been trapped inside the Pokemon world.

Comment: @chris Ok, so I think we can agree that this applies to our world too, I removed it.

Comment: What makes you think the first overload will always be selected?

Comment: Please accept an answer by clicking the checkmark beside it **instead of** changing the title.

Answer (score 2):

`const` is a hint to *yourself* and other developers, that you don't intend to modify the observed object. The const overload is selected if the argument is const:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(const int&)
{
    std::cout << "f(const int&)\n";
}

void f(int&)
{
    std::cout << "f(int&)\n";
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    const int b = 0;
    int& c = a;
    const int& d = a;
    f(a);
    f(b);
    f(c);
    f(d);
}
```

This will output

```
f(int&)
f(const int&)
f(int&)
f(const int&)
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/wY7EmU).

As you can see, it is not always the `const` overload.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference betweeen `void func(const int& i)` and `void func(int& i)`.

The difference bettween `void func(const int& i)` and `void func(int& i)` is that you cannot change `i` in the first function, while you can in the second.

> is it even possible to call the second overload?

The second function will be selected if the argument is not `const`.

> Why are `const` overloads preferred?

It depends. You cannot use `const` if you plan to change its value. And you should use `const` when you want to be sure not to change variable accidentally or intentionally.  Check out this post: [Use const wherever possible in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285773/use-const-wherever-possible-in-c) for more info.

Comment: At least not legally (evil laughter).

Comment: But the const overloads are not always preferred.

Comment: @juanchopanza It depends on the purpose. Cannot use `const` if need to change its value. Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It does not depend on the purpose. The language has rules for this, and they contradict OP's claims.