# gcc (mac/linux) error no matching function for call while VisualStudio compiles ok

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, gcc

I've got a problem with a cross-platform compile.
The code below compiles on Win, Mac and Linux (program is Qt based) but in order to make it compile on the Mac and Linux I have to defined if/else.

Windows compiler (VS2010) finds the definition but Mac (gcc4.2) and Linux (Ubuntu12LTS) cant find it...

Any ideas? Maybe Im missing some technical terminology in order to search for this?
I want to be able to use "table->setMark(i,MyObj());" for all systems as it doesnt seem to have any platform specific code.

```
///// .h
   void setMark(int row, MyObj& mark) 
      { value(row).setMark(mark); }
   const MyObj& getMark(int row) const
      { return value(row).getMark(); }
/////


///// .cpp
   MyObj obj;
   bool ret = false, ifhandled = false;
   m_root_command.evaluate(obj,ret,ifhandled);

   if (m_marked) {
      Table *table = m_thisobj.getTable();
      for (int i = 0; i < table->getRowCount(); i++) {
#if defined(_WIN32)
         // this works in windows, but fails to compile
         // on other platforms with error below
         table->setMark(i,MyObj());
#else
         // I want to get rid of this workaround
         // and use the above code for all platforms
         MyObj objTmp = MyObj();
         table->setMark(i,objTmp);
#endif
      }
      m_marked = false;
   }
/////

///// Error
program.cpp: In member function 'MyObj Program::evaluate()':
program.cpp:264:36: error: no matching function for call to 'Table::setMark(int&, MyObj)'
program.cpp:264:36: note: candidate is:
table.h:326:9: note: void Table::setMark(int, MyObj&)
table.h:326:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'MyObj' to 'MyObj&'
make: *** [program.o] Error 1
/////
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference. To use `table->setMark(i,MyObj());` you need to change the declaration

```
void setMark(int row, MyObj& mark)
```

into

```
void setMark(int row, const MyObj& mark)
```

Likewise for the `setMark` that the function delegates to.

Edit: the fact it works in VS is apparently a [known bug/feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189420/one-vs2010-bug-allowing-binding-non-const-reference-to-rvalue-without-even-a-w)

Comment: What I don't understand is that the code that's compiling on OSes other than Windows is not using a temporary, but a local variable. It should be able to be properly passed to that function as a non-const parameter in this case, shouldn't it?

Comment: This requires the use of a crystal ball since OP's question seems a bit ambiguous. He wants to get rid of the macros and replace it with `table->setMark(i,MyObj());` on all platforms. And that hypothetical code fails to compile with that error. So, I'm guessing that currently shown code actually compiles without errors.

Comment: I have changed the declaration but I get an error again: void setMark(int row, const MyObj& mark) { value(row).setMark(mark); } //
In member function 'void Table::setMark(int, const MyObj&)':
error: no matching function for call to 'Table::setMark(const MyObj&)'
note: candidate is:
note: void Table::setMark(MyObj&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const MyObj' to 'MyObj&'

Comment: Did you forget to change the declaration of the function that `void setMark(int row, const MyObj& mark)` delegates to? The ref parameter of that function must also be const because you cannot bind a const ref into a non-const ref.

Comment: I dont seem to understand what the 'declaration of the function that XX delegates to' means in this context.. (not a native speaker :( ) this function has one line one inline code in the .h file so I just updated the .h to `void setMark(int row, const MyObj& mark)`

Comment: I don't speak English natively either. What I mean is that inside `void setMark(int row, const MyObj& mark)` you call `value(row).setMark(mark);`. According to the new error, that other function expects the parameter to be non-const. However, since you correctly changed the reference to be const, it can no longer be bound to that parameter. Therefore, you must also change the declaration of that other function (`void Table::setMark(MyObj&)` -> `void Table::setMark(const MyObj&))`. In general, you should always declare all references const, unless you intend to modify the referenced object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the problem resides in the #if clause.

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
     table->setMark(i,MyObj());
#else
```

The setMark code it's only being executed on windows, because that's the only place where the #if defined(_WIN32) clause is true. If you remove the #if clause, it should work ok on both Mac OS and Linux.

Comment: There is the `#else` that causes the next two line to compile instead. I don't know why it's necessary though.

Comment: True. I don't see any need for it either. That's why I said to remove the #if clause entirely. Perhaps I didn't express myself very well. My idea was to remove the #if clause and it's else. That way the table->setMark(i,MyObj()); will be executed every time in all Operating Systems, thus removing the need to create the temporary object.

Comment: You propably missunderstood my question! (Im not a native speaker so forgive my writing!). I know about my if define, else thing. I did it in order to overcome the problem. The question is WHY: table->setMark(i,MyObj()); <--- this line cannot compile on GCC. thanks