# non-const reference to rvalue

Tags: c++, constants

I understand the use of `foo(const int& a)`. This can be used to call something like `foo(1)` where for `foo(int& a)` will fail.

Now experimenting I created this class:

```
class temp {
public:
    int a;
    temp(int x = 5) : a(x) {}
    void foo_val(temp a) { /* ... */ }
    void foo_ref(temp& a) { /* ... */ }
}; 

void main() {
    temp temp1(6);
    temp1.foo_val(temp1); // foo_val(temp a) is called
    temp1.foo_ref(temp()); // foo_ref (temp& a) is called
}
```

What I don't understand is why does the `temp1.foo_ref(temp())` succeed. How can we have a reference with a rvalue (`temp()` in this case). I was expecting it to succeed only with `foo_ref(const temp& a)`. Am I thinking about rvalue incorrectly.

Comment: It should [not compile](http://rextester.com/SWDJ93223). Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Which compiler? Visual Studio has a non-standard extension to allow that kind of code, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189420/one-vs2010-bug-allowing-binding-non-const-reference-to-rvalue-without-even-a-w).

Comment: @songyuanyao VS 2015.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Thanks. Never thought this can be a bug.

Comment: @ArulMoondra: It's not

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Yes, an extension, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why does the `temp1.foo_ref(temp())` succeed.

Judging by use of `void main() { ... }`, you must have an old or non-standards compliant compiler.

```
temp1.foo_ref(temp());
```

should fail. I get the following error using g++ 4.8.4.

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11     socc.cc   -o socc

socc.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
socc.cc:13:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘temp::foo_ref(temp)’
  temp1.foo_ref(temp()); //foo_ref (temp& a) is called
                      ^
socc.cc:13:22: note: candidate is:
socc.cc:6:7: note: void temp::foo_ref(temp&)
  void foo_ref(temp& a){}
       ^
socc.cc:6:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘temp’ to ‘temp&’
```

Comment: VS 2015 is hardly "old".

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, old or non-standards compliant.

Comment: Your answer solves my problem. Thank You.